# How to make full screen mode in pygbag?

Tags: python, pygame, pygbag

When I open the pygame html page created with pygbag, the console opens in full screen and the pygame window is in the corner: (see image below)

How can I make the pygbag window open in full screen?

[image: 1]

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation on adding other [templates](https://pygame-web.github.io/wiki/pygbag/#using-other-templates)?

Comment: You helped me.
Leave this question again, not as a comment, but as an answer, so I can mark it.

Comment: You are permitted to [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). For [`pygbag`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=pygbag), there aren't many questions on this site, so it's likely your question will be returned by anyone searching. So a detailed answer may be very useful.

Comment: Check out the documentation on adding other templates <https://pygame-web.github.io/wiki/pygbag/#using-other-templates>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer, you cannot, no web browser will allow your code to switch to fullscreen on page load without user intervention.

So now the default in pygbag is "fullscreen windowed" : that way pygame screen is always maximized inside the page which seems a good trade off.

To get console back, just add #debug to the url

but once user is -already- interacting with pygame, you can call real full screen via python with same code you would use on desktop.